# In Scrum, how do vertical slices work with database scemas?

Tags: schema, agile, scrum, object-relational-model

I've just finished two days of agile/scrum coaching at work which was great. I'm a a novice to professional programming so I needed it. However, I'm struggling very much with the notion of vertical slicing. In particular I cannot see how a database schema can emerge from several developers working separately across all development tiers (front middle and back)? Designing the database schema all in one go is called horizontal slicing and it's considered a no-no. I'm familiar with object relational mapping - slightly - from having worked with frameworks like Grails. But again, I still designed the schema first and worked from there.

To be clear, I am not arguing against the case for agile/scrum/vertical slicing, rather I am asking how it is possible? - in particular when it comes the mapping of objects the the database schema, how can this be done by several developers in tandem and not from the beginning?

This article which i really like seems to - if i've read it correctly - suggest that the database schema should be designed in the spring planning stage before any user stories are implemented.http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/notes-from-the-lab/data-modeling-in-agile-development-one-data-modelers-experience

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (You can also flag for moderator intervention to have this question migrated.)

Comment: I think nobody really understood this question. We can rephrase it so that it actually fits SO. What you need is a tool that prevents you from updating the database simultaneously. For example: https://dbup.github.io/

Answer (score 2):

The idea of a vertical slice is that you do the minimum amount needed to deliver some functionality.

Now it could be that the minimum amount of database design you need to do for the first story is the complete schema. But I think that is unlikely.

For example, to get the first bit of functionality working, do you need the tables related to authentication? What about the tables that do auditing? Maybe some parts of the schema are not related to certain functionality. Say you have a shopping basket application and one aspect of the schema relates to customer's saving their favourite look-and-feel. Could that part of the schema be left until the corresponding story is started?

If you have several developers following this approach then it is going to require a lot of conversation and coordination. Continuous integration of the database schema can really help. So as a developer makes changes to the schema regression tests are run to ensure it hasn't interfered with the other developers work.

Comment: Interesting. I see your point. But others have argued that programmers who relytoo much on ORM's instead of solid data modelling eventually run into problems. I thought a basic schema in the sprint planning stage would give everyone some basic guidance to stick together. What do you think? https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/3ikhn2/martin_fowler_on_orm_hate/

Comment: The agile approach is a compromise. It is saying we want to accommodate change, but in return we are willing to not tie ourselves in too much to one particular direction. Given unchanging requirements your approach is likely to be the better one. But if you want the flexibility to deliver working software at the earliest opportunity you might need to compromise that approach.

Answer (score 1):

This post explains it pretty well: http://blogs.adobe.com/agile/2013/09/27/splitting-stories-into-small-vertical-slices/

You do not necessarily have to have different people working on each piece of the vertical slice. It is more about breaking each part into smaller pieces to achieve incremental results.

From the above article:

> Each slice is comprised of any work needed to be done in an architectural layer as well as any testing and integration that may need to be done to make it ready to release.

Comment: I read that article actually, but it didn't help me.  Breaking things into smaller problems sounds great, but I can't see any way to break down a data schema and have several people put it back together, each working independently.

Comment: See this article : http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/notes-from-the-lab/database-modeling-in-scrum-teams it gives a better explanation. As I said its not necessary that more than one developer be working on a piece at any one time.

Comment: That was much better. What does this quote mean exactly: "During the task planning process, the client ought to be informed that creating features involves a database design. Furthermore, it is a good idea to make design a separate component of User Stories"  Is he saying that the schema shouldn't be part of user stories, that it should be done horizontally?

Comment: I found an excellent article - linked in my updated question - from the same site you linked. It's helped very much.